Making async and multithreaded operations (queries to a bd) in jupyter notebooks
So i wnat to know if there's a point in making an async and multithreaded queries to a mysql bd, and how can we possibly do this in jupyter notebooks.
How can we insert big tables in mysql efficiently.
And if there are any other things that need to be highlighted i would appreciate to know.
Right now i have two async queries that i'm awating at the same time and there's no differense if i make a smaller batches or pass more tasks at the same time. It loads 6-8 threads for maximum 20%
async function execute_query_async(session, query):
    try:
        start_time = current_time()
        result = await session.execute(text(query))
        print('Query executed:', current_time() - start_time)
        start_time = current_time()
        df = create_dataframe(result)
        print('Query executed with DataFrame:', current_time() - start_time)
        return df
    finally:
        await session.close()

async function make_merged_df(queries):
    start_time = current_time()
    tasks = []
    for query in queries:
        task = create_task(execute_query_async(async_session(), query))
        tasks.append(task)
    dataframes = await gather_tasks(tasks)
    merged_df = merge_dataframes(dataframes)
    return merged_df

async function get_df_of_a_thread(users_list):
    chunk_size = length(users_list) // 2
    user_chunks = split_users_into_chunks(users_list, chunk_size)
    tasks = []
    for users in user_chunks:
        queries = generate_queries(users)
        task = create_task(make_merged_df(queries))
        tasks.append(task)
    dataframes = await gather_tasks(tasks)
    concatenated_df = concatenate_dataframes(dataframes)
    print('Processed dataframes:', concatenated_df.shape)

async function main():
    start = 0
    step = 400
    iter = calculate_iterations(users_list, step)
    print(f'Total iterations: {iter}')
    for k in range(iter):
        local_time = current_time()
        end = start + step
        get_list = users_list[start:end]
        await get_df_of_a_thread(get_list)
        print('Time taken:', end - start)
        start = end

